# How to get beginning of day of any epochtime in scala?

Tags: java, scala, epoch

For example:

```
 epochtime = 1450575628  [Sun, 20 Dec 2015 01:40:28]
```

my output should be: `1450569600 [Sun, 20 Dec 2015 00:00:00]`

How to write scala script working for any random epochtime??

Comment: `epochtime - epochtime % 86400` ?

Answer (score 1):

## java.time

Using the [`java.time`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework built into Java 8 and later, available from Scala.

```
import java.time._

val dateFromEpoch = LocalDateTime
  .ofInstant(Instant.ofEpochSecond(1450575628), ZoneId.of("UTC"))
  .`with`(LocalTime.MIN)

dateFromEpoch.toEpochSecond(ZoneOffset.UTC) # Long = 1450569600
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
// construct a new Date object from the given time
Date date = new Date(epochtime * 1000);

// get the calendar and set its time
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(date);

// reset hours to zero (do the same for minutes and seconds)
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR, 0);

// construct Date object after modifications
Date newDate = cal.getTime();
System.out.println(newDate);

// now you can get epoch time from the last object
epochtime = newDate.getTime();
```